# parse line from file to list in c c90

Tags: c, list, pointers, ansi-c, pointer-to-pointer

I'm working with c90 on linux.
I have a strange bug when I want to end a string,
let idx be the index, so when I get to the last index I want the list[idx] to be NULL.
example:

```
list[0] actually "hello"
list[1] actually "world\n"
list[2] sometimes is "" or NULL
```

so when I put NULL to the the end of the list its deletes one of the other words..

for: `list[2] = NULL;`

unexpectedly `list[0] turns NULL` but `list[1] still "world\n"` and `list[2] of course NULL`.

I wrote this function:

```
void function()
{

    char buffer[BUFF_LEN];
    char** list = NULL;
    int list_len = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFF_LEN, fptr))
    {
        list = (char**)malloc((sizeof(char*)));
        get_input(buffer, list, &list_len);
        /*
        some other code
        */
    }
    free_list(list, list_len); /*free the array of strings words*/
}
```

and wrote also the get_input because I work with c90

```
void get_input(char* line, char** list, int *idx)
{
    char * token;
    *idx = 0;
    token = strtok(line, " "); /*extract the first token*/
    /* loop through the string to extract all other tokens */
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        if (token && token[0] == '\t')
            memmove(token, token + 1, strlen(token));
        printf("%s\n", token); 
        list[*idx] = (char *)malloc(strlen(token)+1);
        strncpy(list[*idx], token, strlen(token));
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");   /*get every token*/
        (*idx)++;
    }
    if (*idx == 0)
        list = NULL;
    list[*idx - 1][strcspn(list[*idx - 1], "\n")] = 0; /* remove the "\n" */
    list[*idx] = NULL; /* to know when the list ends */
}
```

the free function:

```
void free_list(char** list, int list_len)
{
    int i;
    for(i= list_len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        list[i] = NULL;
        free(list[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `list = (char**)malloc((sizeof(char*)));` There is no `list[1]` you only allocate memory for one pointer.

Comment: `if (*idx == 0) list = NULL; list[*idx - 1][...]=...` That won't fly. First of all, `list=NULL` will not be visible after leaving that function. Second, assigning something to `NULL[-1][...]=...` doesn't look like a great idea. There should be an `else` I guess...

Comment: Idx is never negative, and i’m freeing the list in the end of the function, adding an edit for that.

Comment: @Gerhardh so for the first message, first allocation what should be the fix, I don't know how much words there will be actually...

Comment: I do not mean a negative `idx`. But if it is 0 as you check in that `if`, then `idx-1` will be negative. And the pointer is set to `NULL` in the previous line.

Comment: If you don't know the number in advance, a) start with a value that is guaranteed to be large enough and shrink afterwards or b) start with some decent/random size and increase if it is not sufficient. `realloc` is your friend.

Comment: Another issue: You allocate a new `list` within your `while` loop but you only free it once after that loop. All allocations except the last one will be lost and cause memory leaks.

Comment: Why are you working with a standard that is probably considerably older than you are?  You should be using C11 (C18 even, though they're essentially the same); you should not be use a relic from the last millennium.  Using C90 will teach you bad habits.  It is not as stringent as modern C.

Comment: @Gerhardh I have a function that freeing it, I didn't wanted to make this question too long but ok, added an edit

Comment: `list[i] = NULL; free(list[i]);` You constantly tend to setting pointers to `NULL` before you use them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Tell that to my University hahaha

Comment: The line `strncpy(list[*idx], token, strlen(token));` ensures that the byte arrays are not null terminated.  You should be using `strcpy()` after ensuring you've allocated enough space (which you have).  Using `malloc()` does not ensure that the memory is zero-initialized — using `calloc()` would, but is unnecessary if you use `strcpy()`.

Comment: Time to worry about the standard of education they are offering you.  They should have updated their courses over the last 5 years; they should not still be teaching the material from yesteryear.

Comment: When Jonathan Leffler wrote "last 5 years", he probably actually meant "20 years". Already C99 introduced lots of improvements. Not adapting to that version (or a newer one) during last 22 years should be treated as refusing to do their job and what they are paid for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues.

```c
void function()
{
    char buffer[BUFF_LEN];
    char** list = NULL;
    int list_len = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFF_LEN, fptr))
    {
        list = (char**)malloc((sizeof(char*)));
        get_input(buffer, list, &list_len);
        /*
        some other code
        */
    }
    free_list(list, list_len); /*free the array of strings words*/
}
```

You only allocate memory for 1 pointer.
You only free the pointers in the last `list`.
You never free the memory for `list` ifself.
You should not cast the return value of `malloc` and friends.

This should be changed like this:

```c
void function()
{
    char buffer[BUFF_LEN];
    char** list = NULL;
    int list_len = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFF_LEN, fptr))
    {
        list = malloc((sizeof(char*)));
        get_input(buffer, &list, &list_len);
        /*
        some other code
        */
        free_list(list); /*free the array of strings words*/
        free(list);
    }
}
```

The freeing function is also broken:

```c
void free_list(char** list, int list_len)
{
    int i;
    for( i= list_len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        list[i] = NULL;
        free(list[i]);
    }
}
```

You set the pointer within `list` to `NULL` before you free it. This causes a memory leak as the memory is not really freed.
You don't really need the length as you have added a sentinel. But that is not an error.
There is also no need to free the pointers backwards.

After cleanup the function could look like this:

```c
void free_list(char** list)
{
    while (list[i])
    {
        free(list[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Now the biggest part:

```c
void get_input(char* line, char** list, int *idx)
{
    char * token;
    *idx = 0;
    token = strtok(line, " "); /*extract the first token*/
    /* loop through the string to extract all other tokens */
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        if (token && token[0] == '\t')
            memmove(token, token + 1, strlen(token));
        printf("%s\n", token); 
        list[*idx] = (char *)malloc(strlen(token)+1);
        strncpy(list[*idx], token, strlen(token));
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");   /*get every token*/
        (*idx)++;
    }
    if (*idx == 0)
        list = NULL;
    list[*idx - 1][strcspn(list[*idx - 1], "\n")] = 0; /* remove the "\n" */
    list[*idx] = NULL; /* to know when the list ends */
}
```

You do not care about memory for the pointers in your `list`. That means you store the pointers in memory that you are not allowed to touch. By doing this you invoke undefined behaviour.
You must `realloc` the memory and for that you must be able to modify the passed pointer.
You should not cast the return values of `malloc` and friends.
You access illegal index values if `*idx==0`
You call `strncpy` with the length of the string without space for the 0 byte. That will cause the copy to be not nul terminated. Also there is no need to use `strncpy` over `strcpy` as you have reserved enough memory.

```c
void get_input(char* line, char*** list, int *idx)
{
    char *token;
    char **list_local = *list; // Make things easier by avoiding one * within the function.
    *idx = 0;
    token = strtok(line, " "); /*extract the first token*/

    /* loop through the string to extract all other tokens */
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        if (token[0] == '\t')  // No need to check for `token` again
            memmove(token, token + 1, strlen(token));

        printf("%s\n", token); 

        list_local[*idx] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
        strcpy(list_local[*idx], token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");   /*get every token*/
        (*idx)++;

        /* Increase array size to hold 1 more entry. */
        /* That new element already includes memory for the sentinel NULL */
        {
            char ** temp = realloc(list_local, sizeof(char*) * (*idx));
            if (temp != NULL)            
                list_local = temp;
            // TODO: error handling ...
        }

    }
    if (*idx != 0)
    {
        list_local[*idx - 1][strcspn(list_local[*idx - 1], "\n")] = 0; /* remove the "\n" */
    }

    list_local[*idx] = NULL; /* to know when the list ends */
    *list = list_local;
}
```